Ubuntu 24.04 has encountering touchpad issues
Yesterday, I was updating important package, a few hours later, as I restarted the laptop, my touchpad stopped moving from one place, it's still stuck at one position.
This issue resolved (Wed Aug 28, 11:08).
But I can't scroll horizontally on my Ubuntu system.
It seems to be a driver issue, but I still can't figure it out.
The touchpad driver shows : ELAN 1200 
Status: Updatable

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Turn the computer off. Try again.
